SFMC Push Sendlogging via Push REST API messageContact "Outbound - API Triggered" message type
Is it possible to send log (push send log de) using fields passed in a API call, using the Standard push rest API - messageContact - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_push/postMessageContactSendPush.html
We're passing additional fields in the payload (ContactKey, TimeSent, CommCode), but these are not being logged.  Title and MessageText are also not being sendlogged
    {
  "subscriberKeys": [
    "Test_123"
    ],    
    "Override": true,
    "title": "this is an alert",
    "MessageText": "this is an alert message",
    "OpenDirect": "OD01",
    "ContactKey": "Test_123",
    "TimeSent":"2024-04-21 10:10:01",
    "CommCode": "ALT123TEST",

We've tried setting Ampscript variables in the send definition but still no sendlogging
%%[
Set @TimeSent = "Alert"
Set @ContactKey = _Subscriberkey
Set @CommCode= CommCode
]%%

any pointers much appreciated
